# how to get scheduled API response in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am new to Azure Logic Apps. I want to create recurring task to poll 3rd party API. Below are the steps of my logic app:

1. Recurrence
2. HTTP
3. Response

After creating the Response action I am getting a warning message "Response actions will not work when added to workflows triggered by recurrence."

I've tried to wrap steps 2 and 3 inside the Scope action, but it didn't resolve the warning. Would appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah response action only work if you have an http trigger

Comment: When it's a recurrence it is just triggering the flow at start and not as a request so it doesn't await for response.You may do a call logic app which has trigger as http and the response would go to that particular API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I have to explain what “Response” action is for. We use “Response” action when we receive requests from others and then we make response to them. Usually we receive requests with http trigger, and then we should response to the one who made the request.

Now, we can have a further investigation on your issue. We will find that, no one make requests to you. In your follow, all activities are triggered by a “Recurrence trigger”. We have no need to make a response to it.

In your logic app, when “Recurrence trigger” is triggered as scheduled, a http request will be sent to third party API. Then the third party will response. Considering of your design, I am thinking that you might want to tell the server that you get its response. If so, you do not need to do that at all.

In conclusion, when triggered by “Recurrence trigger”, we do not need to perform a “Response” action.

Comment: We may need a response to see if API failed or passed